# Did I write these HTML img tags correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

What I'm wanting to do here is stack these images on top of one another using the z-index property and change the z-index to make the other images appear on top using the buttons. I tried to do this by setting the images all in the same spot and then use the javascript function to change the z-index properties of the images in accordance with the button. It's not a very beautiful way to do it but I can't think of another way besides using the visibility property. Would anyone be able to help me implement my view on how this should work. Can't really figure it out form here.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<center><img src="/tools/c_clamps.jpg" id="tool1" height="248" width="364" style = "position:absolute; z-index:1";></center>
<center><img src="/tools/crescent_wrench.jpg" id="tool2" height="248" width="364" style = "position:absolute; z-index:0";></center>
<center><img src="/tools/chisels.jpg" id="tool3" height="248" width="364" style = " position:absolute; z-index:-1";></center>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
//<![CDATA[
function select(picture){
    if(picture == 1)
    {
        document.getElementByID("tool1").z-index:1;
        document.getElementByID("tool2").z-index:0;
        document.getElementByID("tool3").z-index:-1;
    }
    else if(picture == 2)
    {
        document.getElementByID("tool1").z-index:0;
        document.getElementByID("tool2").z-index:1;
        document.getElementByID("tool3").z-index:-1;
    }
    else if(picture == 3)
    {
        document.getElementByID("tool1").z-index:-1;
        document.getElementByID("tool2").z-index:0;
        document.getElementByID("tool3").z-index:1;
    }
}
//]]>
//-->
</script>
<br/>
  <div width="400" style="display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right:     auto;text-align: center">
<button type = "button" onclick="select(1);">Clamps</button>
<button type = "button" onclick="select(2);">Chisels</button>
<button type = "button" onclick="select(3);">C. Wrench</button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note it's [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Also there are several other  problems here, for example `.z-index` is not how you access that property in JavaScript because the`-` isn't valid for a property name instead you need to use `zIndex`. And you use `=` for assignment, not `:`.

Comment: The `zIndex` is accessed as `node.style.zIndex`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still fairly new with this type of stuff so I find myself making a lot of mistakes that I can't find.

Comment: The `<center>` element is obsolete as of HTML5 as is the 'language' attribute for `<script>` and "text/javascript" is not necessary and is the default.

Comment: It should be noted that CSS `'z-index'` syntax is accessible in its non camelCase form on CSS2Properties objects (such a `Element.style`) with the bracket notation (e.g `Element.style['z-index']`, or `Element.style['border-top-left-radius']`). This can be handy when parsing CSS syntax input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the syntax should be :

```
 document.getElementById("tool1").style.zIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

slight changes for your javascript:

Instead of:

```
document.getElementByID("tool1").z-index:1;
```

it should be:

```
document.getElementById("tool1").style.zIndex = 1;
```

Fix all those, it might work!

Comment: Might? Great confidence there!

Comment: You can use backticks or indentations to format the code in your answer.